# Rmarkdown to Epub - how to get latex to show up?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I've been writing some documents with Knitr and Rmarkdown to .pdf, but it turns out I need to have then in .epub format instead.

I had been running a command like this to convert the .md files to .epub.

```
pandoc --mathjax -s --highlight-style tango file.md --to epub -o output.epub
```

That seems to have some issue handling latex code, though. Inline latex code with `$x_1$`, for example, seems to work fine. However, for latex blocks like:

```
$$
x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1 \\
h(x) = f(-20 + 15 + 17) \\
h(x) = f(12) \approx 1 \\
$$
```

It just displays the raw latex:

```
\[ x\_1 = 1, x\_2 = 1 \\\\ h(x) = f(-20 + 15 + 17) \\\\ h(x) = f(12) \\approx 1 \\\\ \]
```

Am I using latex for multi-line equations wrong in Rmarkdown? Is there a recommended way to get big chunks of latex working with Epub?

Answer (score 1):

From [Creating an ebook with pandoc](https://pandoc.org/epub.html#math)
:

> Pandoc has an EPUB3 writer. It renders LaTeX math into MathML, which EPUB3 readers are supposed to support (but unfortunately few do). Use pandoc -t epub3 to force EPUB3 output, as opposed to EPUB2 which is the default.
>
> Of course, this isn't much help if you want EPUB2 output or target readers that don't support MathML. Then you should try using the `--webtex` option, which will use a web service to convert the TeX to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't really reproduce your issue (at least the line breaks are discarded) -- eventually it's worth to use some more latex code for your equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{eq7}
x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1 \\
h(x) = f(-20 + 15 + 17) \\
h(x) = f(12) \approx 1 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```